# Lie Symmetries: How to check b.c. of ODE without determining explicit symmetry solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups

I am trying to solve this ODE using symmetry methods.

$$y''(x)=ay'(x)$$

With the boundary condition $y(0)=0$ and $y(\infty)=y_\infty $.

The base solution is $y(x)=y_{\infty}(1-e^{ax})$.

I found 8 one parameter symmetry groups. For the first four symmetries I was able to calculate the explicit form of the symmetry solution. But the fifth group is quiet hard.

For the first group $G_1 (x,y+\varepsilon)$ I did the following:

$$\hat{x}=x$$
$$\hat{y}=y(x)+\varepsilon$$

Then I solved for $x$ in the first equation and plugged the result into the second equation to obtain:

$$\hat{y}=y(\hat{x})+\varepsilon.$$

It is easy to see that this does not satisfy the b.c. if $y(x)=y_\infty(1-e^{ax})$, as 
$$\hat{y}(\hat{x}=0)=y(\hat{x}=0)+\varepsilon=0+\varepsilon\neq0.$$

I was able to use this method up to group $G_4$, but failed at $G_5$.

$$G_5: \left[a\left(
   2\pi ik_1+\ln\left(\exp\left(ax-2\pi ik_1\right)
   +a\varepsilon y
   \right)
 \right),y\right]$$

I tried the following:

$$\hat{x}=a\left(
   2\pi ik_1+\ln\left(\exp\left(ax-2\pi ik_1\right)
   +a\varepsilon y
   \right)
 \right)$$
$$\hat{y}=y(x)$$

I solved for $x$ but it still contains $y$ in it. How can I check the boundary conditions without the explicit symmetry solution? Is there maybe a way to even use the infinitesimal generators to so?

Thank you for reading my questions.